# How to animate the "value" of input[type="submit"] on hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have successfully applied an animation to standard buttons/a links in my site. I overlooked the fact that some buttons are input[type="submit"] for forms etc. so my setup on standard buttons won't work in this instance.

I wondered if there is a way to animate the value of an input with jQuery?

I've tried researching this but haven't found anything that might help so hoping someone here can provide some guidance?

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wktL81bd/1/) to provide an example of where I'm at.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="btn"><span>Button 1</span></a>

<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Button 2">
```

**SCSS**

```
@keyframes wiggle {
  0%, 100%, 20%, 50%, 80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform:     translateX(0);
    transform:         translateX(0)
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-4px);
    -ms-transform:     translateX(-4px);
    transform:         translateX(-4px)
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px);
    -ms-transform:     translateX(-2px);
    transform:         translateX(-2px)
  }
}

.btn {
  span {
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }

  &:hover,
  &:not([disabled]):hover {
    span {
      animation-name: wiggle;
      -webkit-animation-name: wiggle;
      -moz-animation-name: wiggle;
      -o-animation-name: wiggle;
      -ms-animation-name: wiggle;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you may use `button[type="submit"]` and put a `span` in it then animate that `span`.

Comment: Omg! I'm so silly, I completely overlooked this. Thanks you so much for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your animation is applied to span, you only have span inside tag  and not in the input. Try to apply you animation on entire button, test your fiddle edited with animation rule outside span:

https://jsfiddle.net/12bxcvh6/1/

```
.btn {
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

  &:hover,
  &:not([disabled]):hover {
      animation-name: wiggle;
      -webkit-animation-name: wiggle;
      -moz-animation-name: wiggle;
      -o-animation-name: wiggle;
      -ms-animation-name: wiggle;
  }
```